# rsyslog.conf: kern.err /dev/console. Where do these messages go?

Tags: linux, logging, console, dev

There is a commented line in rsyslog.conf:

```
#kern.*         /dev/console
```

If I add this line to the configuration file:

```
kern.notice       /dev/console
```

Where do these messages go?

If I run this command:

```
logger -p kern.notice "Log Message Test"
```

Where will I see the message?

If I want to display the message on the terminal I use `omusrmsg`

Console is the same as terminal right?

When I fired this command:

```
echo "Testing" > /dev/console
```

nothing happened.

Where exactly does it go?

Answer (score 0):

Here "Console" means the *primary* terminal.

The special `/dev/console` device node usually corresponds to what the kernel thinks to be the primary console, and *that* usually means whichever tty is in foreground (from tty1…tty63). On embedded systems, it might be redirected to a serial port using the `console=` kernel option.

Generally, in Unix, you might notice programs distinguishing between "console login" (directly at the PC) vs "remote / network login".

Comment: So where will I be able to see the log messages that are directed to /dev/console?